# cakephp updateAll not working

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code:

```
$this->Permissions->updateAll(
    array('Permissions.user' => $newuser), 
    array('Permissions.user' => $originaluser)
);
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'counterstaff' in 'field list' [APP\cake\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 681]

Query: UPDATE `permissions` AS `Permissions` SET `Permissions`.`user` = counterstaff WHERE `Permissions`.`user` = 'counter'
```

for some reason it thinks the value that I want to set is a column. Anyone have any ideas why this is the happening?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem with the update query is put the value in quotation something like

```
    UPDATE `permissions` AS `Permissions` SET
 `Permissions`.`user` = "counterstaff" WHERE 
`Permissions`.`user` = 'counter'
```

Comment: This answer doesn't help at all when using Cake.

Answer (score 15):

Fixed it! I had to add single quotes around my variable like so:

```
$this->Permissions->updateAll(
    array('Permissions.user' => "'".$newuser."'"), 
    array('Permissions.user' => $originaluser)
);
```

Comment: SQL injection is possible this way. `updateAll` gets SQL expressions as params, not values as other CakePHP funcs do. This is the better value quotation: `$this->Permissions->updateAll(
    array('Permissions.user' => $this->Permissions->value($newuser)), 
    array('Permissions.user' => $originaluser)
);`

Comment: @472084 I believe it's so you can do more complex expressions, which is common in updates.  For instance, this way you can do `updateAll(array('Page.visits' => 'Page.visits + 1'), array('Page.id' => $pageid))`.  That would take two queries otherwise.  And this behavior is well-documented in the [updateAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions) docs.

Answer (score 3):

```
**Use this code for updating your data:** 
$this->Permissions->updateAll(
        array('Permissions.user' => "'$newuser'"), 
        array('Permissions.user' => "'$originaluser'")
    );
```